# wxWidgets cannot open setup.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, wxwidgets, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Stuff I've already done:

- Set the locations of both `(some stuff)\include` and `(some stuff)\include\msvc` in the properties.
- Set the location of the lib.
- Tried static linking (used the ones I've compiled/built manually).
- Tried dynamic linking with the binaries (never forgot about the `WXUSINGDLL`).

I know that there are already similar questions found in this site, yet none of them seem to solve my problem. Firstly, I got rid of the "cannot open" problem by changing the `#define wxTOOLKIT_PREFIX msw` to `#define wxTOOLKIT_PREFIX mswu`, because the folder names seem to be different. Then, I got a linking error "cannot open file wxbase32d.lib". I opened the folder and saw that the names don't match (it has an extra 'u' character).

What should I do? Am I supposed to rename all of them stripping out all the 'u's?

Comment: did you compile the library? did it give you any errors? What compiler do you have? What exact command you used to compile the library?

Comment: in addition - do you use any IDE?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, undo all of your changes, as right now you have your own unique version of the library that nobody can help you with because we don't know what exactly have you changed. If you're not absolutely certain of what you did, delete the existing wxWidgets directory and redownload it again. You must *not* modify anything in wxWidgets sources for it to build.

Second, it looks like you're using MSVS. Unless it's a really ancient version, the [instructions](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.2/docs/msw/install.md#building-applications-using-wxwidgets--msw_build_apps) should work for you, i.e. you only need to add `wxwidgets.props` file to your project. This is the preferred way to build applications using wxWidgets. If, for some reasons, you don't want to do this, you can set up your projects manually, but note that it involves more than just setting up the include directories (notably, your problem with missing "u" are due to not defining `_UNICODE`).